# Sensu API not responding. Uchiwa: Connection error. Is the Sensu API running? Redis Issue

Tags: monitoring, centos7, redis, rabbitmq, sensu

I have been setting up sensu on CentOS7.2 for the first time following the official docs over and over however I have not been able to get it to work:

I cannot seem to connect to the API. Uchiwa gives the error:

```
ALERT
Datacenter site1 returned:
Connection error. Is the Sensu API running?`
```

[image]

I have tried: `curl -I http://localhost:4567/clients`
...I do not get a response.

Here is /var/log/sensu/sensu-api.log
http://pastebin.com/wHEHE0bH

I have been creating a script to make the setup repeatable. Please see my script below which shows my config: http://pastebin.com/QEt5Msku
If you run the script on CentOS7 it should repeat this issue.

### Fix:

Issue in answer below. After following a non official guide that successfully installed sensu on a fresh VM, I compared the two setup steps and after a couple of builds on fresh VMs swapping out the steps bit by bit I figured out replacing the repo with one from a non official guide that pointed to a slightly different URL fixed my problem (repo for CentOS6 but it works on 7, it just installs a non current verson 0.20.3).

```
echo '[sensu]
name=sensu-main
baseurl=http://repos.sensuapp.org/yum/el/6/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1' > /etc/yum.repos.d/sensu.repo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that sensu 0.23 resolves localhost to an ipv6 address but redis is not listening to the ipv6 address. The solution is to change `"host": "localhost"` to `"host": "127.0.0.1"`. There is an issue on [Sensus git page](https://github.com/sensu/sensu/issues/1209)

For your information, you should have looked in the sesu-server logs too and posted them here.

Comment: I actually resolved this at 2AM but went to sleep before posting the answer on here. You are right! I spent so many hours on this as the official documentation looked straightforward until i finally created a new VM and just copy pasted the steps in a poorly made guide that installed using a different repo and installed a slightly older version of sensu.

Answer (score -2):

For anyone seeking more info, you can check out the [Sensu issue](https://github.com/sensu/sensu/issues/1209) related to this bug. The issue for me was a conflict between the default host resolution on my OS, and the default Redis config as installed from the repo. My solution was:

> Update /etc/hosts to resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1 instead of ::1.
>
> *OR*
>
> Update redis.conf to bind to ::1 in addition to 127.0.0.1.
>
> If you're running an IPv6-capable host, the latter option is probably
>   the way to go. Hope this helps!

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: It's better to include the bulk of the relevant details directly in your post/answer; link-only answers are considered very low quality, as links can change/go stale/dead over time.  This would leave future readers without the actual answer.

Comment: The solution is included in my answer. This issue is already linked in my answer.